# Owl Carousel, show child absolute div, over parent overflow hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using owl carousel 2, I am facing following problem.

I have parent `div` with a name `owl-stage-outer`, it has `overflow:hidden` as per requirement of the carousel.

I have another child `div` name: `ribbon` (showing 'New Arrival' and 'Big Sale') which is `position: absolute` Now the problem which I am facing, on first item of carousel, ribbon is hiding because of `overflow: hidden`

[reference image](http://prntscr.com/ajd4gk)

[Link on which I am working](http://202.141.243.212/fantasypartywebsite/elsa-costume.html?options=cart)

I have tried solution provided in this [link](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent), but it will only work on immediate child.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about removing overflow: hidden; property on .owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer ?

Comment: Currently I have only 2 items, if I will remove overflow then all items will be shown :)

Reference of my template:
http://202.141.243.212/fantasypartywebsite/misc/html/product_detail_page.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this `margin-left: 25px;` its works.

```
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 240px;margin-right: 60px;margin-left: 25px;">
```

**EDIT :**

Its works

add this of you `container` :

```
<div class="container" style="
    width: 1220px;
    padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
">
```

of your `owl-stage-outer` :

```
<div class="owl-stage-outer" style="
    overflow: visible;
">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Greg, but problem is, my client is not interest to move items box and should be align with the main container, because in some case there will be no 'New Arrival' ribbon so in that case it looks weird and not aligned with container :)

Comment: Thanks again buddy for quick support, answer accepted (Y)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix (kind of dirty but it works) that you can try :

First you remove `overflow: hidden` of `.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer`. It will show all your slider on 100% of the width of the page, yes.

But then you set `position: relative;` to `.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer` instead of `position: static;`.

Then you add a `:before` on it like this to hide the left part :

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer:before {
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Of course you have to do the same with `:after` to hide the right content.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent, it's working for me but with one issue, if I am removing `overflow hidden`, then horizontal scroll is showing, but I have make body `overflow-y: hidden`, so cheers ;)

Comment: Yeah that's also why it's a dirty fix but it works :) Glad to help !

Comment: @VincentG i tried your method but its not work for me what i have to do like i want this design but its have ribbon vertical so how i do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  margin: -25px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this answers the question.